# How to mine Github for projects with a specific file?

Tags: api, github

I'm conducting an empirical research on Java projects from Github and I wrote a [Python script](https://github.com/jeandersonbc/github-api-wrapper/blob/master/scripts/driver.py) to search for projects using the search API.

However, **what I really would like to do is** to include in my search criteria (Java projects with at least 100 stars) **to fetch only Maven projects** (considering only projects with a pom.xml in the root directory).

So, **how can I search for projects on Github considering only projects that use Maven** (e.g has a "pom.xml" in the root directory)? Is this possible, by any chance?

Because Github API limits the results to the top 1000 entries, I can't just skip ant and gradle projects.

I've been searching in the Github API documentation but didn't find what I'm looking for. In case I find the solution, I will remember to post it here :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this [GitHub search](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=maven%20in%3Aname%2Cdescription%20stars%3A%3E%3D100) query:

```
maven in:name,description stars:>=100
```

It will return all the repos containing the word **maven** in their name or description that were starred **100** times or more.

Comment: Thanks mate! I edited my question. I meant for projects with Maven as a build manager system. In your query, I've got projects with maven in the name. However, I apparently found what I needed with the query https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=stars%3A%3E%3D100+path%3Apom.xml+language%3AJava&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=&l=Java :) Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: just and update here.. instead of maven, I used "mvn" in description and found a lot more maven projects :) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://github.com/search?l=Maven+POM&q=extension%3A.xml+project&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=✓

Basically, search for all the files with extension .xml with a super-common keyword like 'project' in it, then click on the sidebar, under languages, Maven POM.